# Rounding numbers (float) to store them as int, without using math.packe like math.round()

Tags: java, floating-point, int, rounding

Simple program to calculate the Fahrenheit-Temperature from Celsius, but is this possible without using math.round()?

```
public class CelsiusZuFahreheit {
public static void main (String [] args){

    System.out.println("Temperature-Calculation");
    System.out.println("=======================");
    System.out.println("C       F");
    System.out.println("---------");

    for(int celsius = 0; celsius<=100; celsius+=3){
    float fahrenheit = (float)celsius * 9/5 + 32;
    int rFahrenheit = Math.round(fahrenheit);
    System.out.printf("%3d %5d\n", celsius, rFahrenheit);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You could just convert it to an `int` but you would not round the value correctly, the value would end up being just the integer part of the float. E.g. `0.5 -> 0`, `1.999 -> 1` and `2.35 -> 2`

Comment: To round a float to int simply add 0.5 and cast to int.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `Math.round`?

Comment: @HotLicks except if the result is negative :/   Although I admit OP's code never goes there

Comment: Why is everyone being so negative?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

`System.out.printf("%3d %5.0f\n", celsius, fahrenheit);`

As you're rounding the value purely for the presentation purposes then makes sense to move this logic into string formatting.

Moreover leaving the value as double in general is probably a good idea, as the 83.23 is still a valid temperature value (and should your requirement change and you need to print 2 decimal places it will be just 1 character change).

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
int rFahrenheit = (int) (fahrenheit + (fahrenheit>=0 ? 0.5 : -0.5));
```

Comment: This will not round correctly if the number is negative.

Comment: @EmilH - Yeah, but if the temp is negative you don't want to know anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert fahrenheit to string format. Then check for the dot character.Then you can print the value uptill the dot character

Comment: Which will not round any better than simply casting to int.